# Is there a good entry-level tutorial for SPM?

Tags: fmri, spm

The title pretty much says it all.  I need to do some fMRI data analysis and I can't find any entry-level tutorials for Statistical Parameter Mapping (SPM).  I've looked at some of [the videos on the official SPM website](http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/spm/course/video/), but I find that videos are not the most effective way of learning a new computerized tool -- I'm in the market for reading.

Does anybody have a go-to reference that's a bit less verbose and a bit more crash-course-y than the official manual?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way to learn is probably not by reading, but by doing. The SPM website contains a number of useful [datasets with tutorials](http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/spm/data/) for various tasks.

I also find PowerPoint slides from lectures and talks useful. There are a [bunch of slides](http://www.fil.ion.ucl.ac.uk/spm/course/) on the SPM website, but you can also find more on Google by limiting your results to `type:pptx`.